# Ubuntu guest on VirtualBox, add host-only adapter and lose internet connectivity

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, linux-networking

I've got an Ubuntu guest VM in virtualbox. When I add a second network adapter that is host-only, I lose internet connectivity.  All internt traffic gets sent through the second interface, instead of the first bridged interface.

Why this is happening and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have the second adapter set for DHCP.

The adapter is getting a default gateway in addition to the IP address settings, and that default gateway is being used instead of the gateway for your bridged interface.

You could set your DHCP client to not request or use the gateway it receives.  You may be able to adjust the metric.  You could statically assign the address on your host-only interface, and simply not set a gateway.

Comment: thanks so much that was exactly it. i set it to static ip w/ no gateway and now net works. appreciate the help!